# An issue in ORDER BY command SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
qry = "SELECT * FROM courses ORDER BY price DESC "
```

here I have declared **price** as **varchar** for logical reasons, so in case of order it gives

output:

```
{
"id": 5,
"payment_type": "one time",
"price": "1000"
},
{
"id": 11,
"payment_type": "one time",   # issue here
"price": "10000" 
},
{
"id": 10,
"payment_type": "Lumpsum",     # issue here
"price": "12000"
},
{
"id": 2,
"payment_type": "one time",
"price": "3000"
},
{
"id": 13,
"payment_type": "one time",
"price": "3500"
},
{
"id": 12,
"payment_type": "one time",
"price": "4500"
},
```

.... and so on

Can I ordered this price without changing the datatype of this column?

SET : type of column "varchar"
TRYING TO GET : ORDER BY price ASC Or DESC

Comment: Why use varchar for price?

Comment: You'll need to cast `price` to a number otherwise you will get lexicographical sort like you are seeing. `ORDER BY price::int DESC` will likely do the trick. The real issue is storing a number as a `varchar`. Your best off just fixing your table.

Comment: @JNevill 's solution is what I would think to do as well, but if you're using varchar then probably there will be some elements that cannot be cast to a number (otherwise why would you use varchar in the first place). If you expect to use price like a number you'll likely have an easier time using the correct datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use ORDER BY on a string so it tries to sort lexically, one solution would be to cast the type:
SELECT * FROM courses ORDER BY CAST('price' AS decimal) DESC;

Hope it works!